# Where is my thinking wrong? Browser scales simple <div> box

Tags: html, css, chromium, measurement

Today I did a simple test.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
     #box_4cm {
      width: 4cm;
      height: 4cm;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid black;
     }
     #box_223px {
      width: 223.25px;
      height: 223.25px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid black;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="box_4cm"></div>
     <div id="box_223px"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This markdown tests dimensions of two boxes. First box shall be `4cm` in width and `4cm` in height. Second box shall be same size. As for the second box, I measured my screen size, it is `1920x1080px`, `34.4cm`. Then made a calculations. `1cm = 55.81px` -> `4cm = 223.25px`.

As I type this question, I see, from the result of SO code snippet, that boxes are of different size. Also, the first box is 3.5cm in contrast to 4cm. The second box is about 5cm in size. The results are clearly wrong.

Having exported the above HTML to PDF, I have got expected results as for the first box, it is displayed as true 4cm. More than that, having supply my dimensions in pixels I still got wrong real sizes. In other words if I do `#box {width:100px; height:100px;}` result displays different in size. I've checked it with the `gimp` `measure tool`.

So I continue from where I've started. Where is my thinking wrong?

P.S My system is Linux Mint, the browser is Chromium.

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

The above two screen captures show that `#box_223px {width: 223.25px; ... }` has width of `294px`. You can see it in a `gimp` bottom panel.

Comment: Maybe you're converting wrong. I've made a [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/ragaxug/edit?html,css,output) have a look at it. I've obtained conversion value from [here](https://www.unitconverters.net/typography/centimeter-to-pixel-x.htm). 1cm = 96px/2.54 = 37.7952755906

Comment: What did you measure in gimp? Maybe you have active zoom?

Comment: @yunzen As you can see from above screen I did no zoom when measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. `cm`, `in` and other length units are only good for printing.

It's because browsers might know of the pixels of a monitor (through the graphics card), but not about the *real world* dimensions (screen size)

See this quote from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units

> Absolute length units represent a physical measurement when the physical properties of the output medium are known, such as for print layout. This is done by anchoring one of the units to a physical unit, and then defining the others relative to it. The anchor is done differently for low-resolution devices, such as screens, versus high-resolution devices, such as printers.
>
> For low-dpi devices, the unit `px` represents the physical reference pixel; other units are defined relative to it. Thus, `1in` is defined as `96px`, which equals `72pt`. The consequence of this definition is that on such devices, dimensions described in inches (`in`), centimeters (`cm`), or millimeters (`mm`) doesn't necessary match the size of the physical unit with the same name.
>
> For high-dpi devices, inches (`in`), centimeters (`cm`), and millimeters (`mm`) are the same as their physical counterparts. Therefore, the `px` unit is defined relative to them (1/96 of 1 inch).

#### As a result:

Use pixel units for displays, length units will be incorrect.
Use length units for print, maybe pixel units if you don't mind the absolute values.

Comment: It's OK to me with cm, in, pts etc. But `<div>` with pixel dimensions displays wrong too!

Comment: @ЯрославМашко `px` units are exactly that, Pixels. In your browser's developer tools you can check. 'cm' unit is somewhat cumbersome. It may depend on so many things like resolution, pixel density, browser, day of week (ok not that)

Comment: What I mean is `#box {width:100px;}` displays literally wrong in pixels. That part was in my question. What I do now is struggling with gimp to make a good screen of this strange behavior.

Comment: "Thus, 1in is defined as 96px" - this one is strange convention. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're converting it wrong.
1cm = 96px/2.54 = 37.7952755906
4cm = (96px/2.54)*4 = 151.181102362

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
     #box_4cm {
      width: 4cm;
      height: 4cm;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid black;
     }
     #box_151px {
      width: 151.181102362px;
      height: 151.181102362px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid black;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="box_4cm"></div>
     <div id="box_151px"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```